# PyQt5 No encuentra el driver qsqlpsql.dll

Tags: pyqt5, anaconda

Tengo instalado ANACONDA 5.0.0, en Win10, Python 3.6.2, por defecto Anaconda trae PyQT5 pero al ejecutar un programa que intenta conectarse con postgresql9.5 me dice el driver no se ha encontrado.

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado el driver de postgres psycopg2?

Comment: Si lo tenia instalado lo resolvi instalando manualmente el pyqt5 usando pip install PyQt5